# Birth-death process with a single absorbing state which is not $0$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, birth-death-process

I'm working on an issue related to Hyperdimensional Computing. In short, I have a $d$-bit array $v$ sampled uniformly from the space of all $d$-bit binary arrays.

Consider the following process: at each step, I uniformly choose one of the $d$ positions of this vector $v$ and flip the bit. My question is: what is the expected number of steps until the vector obtained is orthogonal ($d/2$ distant) to the initial vector?

What I could think of so far is that this process can be expressed as a birth-death process where state $0$ is not absorbing but another state $d/2$ is. In this case the question would be: what is the expected number of transitions, starting from state $0$, to absorption in state $d/2$?

Thank you so much,

Comment: What do you mean $d$ distant? Is it something like $(1\dots 1)$ is a $d$-bit array and also $(0\dots 0)$. Are these $d$ distant away?

Comment: I assumed the bits were signed, so $\{ 1,-1 \}$ bits, so you need $d/2$ net flips to be orthogonal.

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to mention. I'm referring to the Hamming distance (the number of positions in which the two bits are different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess these are $\{ -1,1 \}$ bits instead of $\{ 0,1 \}$ bits.

If so then yes, assuming $d$ is even, then you can model this as a symmetric random walk which is *a priori* on $0,1,\dots,d$ with reflecting boundaries, but can be restricted to $0,1,\dots,d/2$ by making $d/2$ into an absorbing boundary. This random walk describes the number of bits that are different than the original, so it starts at $0$.

So you have $p_{i,i+1}=(d-i)/d$ for $0 \leq i<d/2$, $p_{i,i-1}=i/d$ for $1 \leq i<d/2$ and $p_{d/2,d/2}=1$. Everything else is zero. Say $u(i)$ is the expected absorption time starting at $i$. By considering starting at each state and conditioning on each possible outcome, you get $u(0)=1+u(1),u(i)=1+\frac{(d-i) u(i+1)+i u(i-1)}{d}$ for $1 \leq i<d/2$ and $u(d/2)=0$. This is a linear system you can solve.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I understood it and I think it is correct.

I don't have much experience solving these linear recurrence relations, so I'm having a bit of trouble. I tried to substitute starting from $u(1)$ but I couldn't find a pattern. I also tried using a symbolic computing tool (sympy) but that didn't work either.

If you have any tips/references it would be very helpful.
Thanks again,

Comment: @IgordeOliveiraNunes Are you asking for a general solution independent of $d$ or do you have a specific $d$ in mind? If you have a specific $d$ in mind, this is just a tridiagonal linear system, very cheap to solve on a computer even if $d$ is huge.

Comment: I was able to describe and solve the system for a given $d$. Perhaps solving for $d$ would be interesting, but the current result is enough for me. Thanks a lot for the help!